# Export entire module through default export

Tags: typescript

I have a module with the following contents:

- a class (called Foo)
- an interface (called Bar)
- an instance of the class (no name)

I want to export all of these via the default export so that I can access them in the following manner:

```js
import foo from './foo'

foo // this is the instance of the class
foo.Foo // the class
foo.Bar // the interface
```

I can do this quite easily by exporting namespaces, however eslint forbids namespaces in favor of regular ES6 export syntax (for good reasons as far as I know).

Comment: What does your tsconfig look like? It can depend based on if you have the ```--isolatedModules``` flag or not

Comment: I did not know of such flag. Will research it, thanks. (I have not set a value for the flag, so I am using the default value).

Answer (score 0):

i personally like named exports more than default exports and you can achieve something close to that by using named exports like this:

in you `[module].ts`

```
class Foo {}
interface Bar {}
const instance = new Foo()

export { Foo, Bar, instance }
```

in the file you are importing:

```
import * as foo from '[path to your module]'
```

and you can use it like this:

```
class Dummy extends foo.Foo {}
class Car implements foo.Bar {}
console.log(foo.instance)
```

you can use the default export to export an object but that will not include the interface since interfaces are types and can't be used as values to assign inside that object.
so you can do something like this:

```
export default {
  instance,
  Foo
}
```

and you can you use like this:

```
import foo from '[path to module]'
class Dummy extends foo.Foo {}
console.log(foo.instance)
// no interface available so this won't work
class Car implements foo.Bar {}
```